# Is SoapHttpClientProtocol thread safe?

Tags: c#, web-services, proxy, thread-safety, asmx

I created a Web Service proxy with the "add web reference" feature of VS 2008 (c#).

The generated class derives from `SoapHttpClientProtocol`

Can I store only one instance of my proxy in a singleton? Is it thread safe? Is there state between calls that would prevent me from doing this?

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It is not thread safe. the client must be in the Open state to enable calls. A simple scenario where one thread does client.Close() while another tries to call a method will fail.

Comment: This class does not have a Close method and has not at least since v3.0. See ChrisW's answer.

Comment: @RiverSatya - the answer was posted 8 years ago

Comment: Yes, and it's out of date. Since it's the accepted answer, I added a pointer to a more up to date one.

Answer (score 11):

MSDN says that [SoapHttpClientProtocol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.soaphttpclientprotocol(v=vs.110).aspx) is thread safe:

> **Thread Safety**
>
> This type is thread safe.

For another class like [System.Windows.Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form(v=vs.110).aspx) which isn't thread-safe, MSDN says,

> **Thread Safety**
>
> Any public static (Shared in Visual Basic) members of this type are
> thread safe. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread
> safe.

---

[Here is a Microsoft/MSDN employee](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t787354-is-soap-client-proxy-that-wsdl-exe-generates-thread-safe.html) saying (though without guarantee) that it is thread-safe:

> Hi Max,
>
> For the webservice proxy, I think it should be thread-safe as the .NET
> generated proxy class is derived from the "SoapHttpClientProtocol"
> class which is marked as thread-safe in document:
>
> ## SoapHttpClientProtocol Class
>
> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.soaphttpclientprotocol(VS.71).aspx
>
> therefore, it should be safe to use it in multi-thread context as long
> as you haven't manually add any context-sensitive member in the
> derived proxy class. Do you think so?
>
> Sincerely,
>
> Steven Cheng
>
> Microsoft MSDN Online Support Lead
>
> This posting is provided "AS IS" with no warranties, and confers no
> rights.

Comment: -1: You are discussing a legacy technology, and linking to an article from .NET 1.1.

Comment: The first link I gave is to the current (.NET 4.5) documentation for the class: which still says that it's thread-safe. The last link I gave is a direct quote from an old forum post by a MSFT employee (to confirm the way in which the MSDN documentation should be understood).

Comment: Neither of which statements contradicts what I said.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Do you have a suggestion for [improving](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructive_criticism) this answer?

Comment: I see: perhaps it's not the answer you don't like specifically, it's the question/topic (which is about "legacy technology").

Comment: With respect, I think that clicking the "delete" link would be an improvement.

Comment: @JohnSaunders I thought I should post it, to correct mis-information: because, so far as I know, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1922247/49942) was wrong.

Comment: Yeah, i really don't know. I guess the wording can be taken at face value: This type is thread safe - both the class and instanced objects. Poking through the code in reflector, i couldn't find anything that would be a race condition. i don't know what John's grumpy about. The question is if SoapHttpClientProtocol is thread safe; not if thinks people should be using it.

Comment: @JohnSaunders I am more interested in knowing how to use the new `ClientBase<T>` class thread-safely (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4625367/is-wcf-clientbase-thread-safe/4625404#comment31671808_4625404) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4625367/is-wcf-clientbase-thread-safe/6281279#comment31652952_6281279), and this new question [Thread-safe access to WCF channel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21047666/thread-safe-access-to-wcf-channel)), if you can answer that?

Comment: @IanBoyd: I think that you're taking a big risk depending on code that's all but unsupported to be thread-safe. What if it turns out that there _is_ a race condition? Do you realize that Microsoft will not fix it? Also, just because the base class is thread safe, that doesn't imply that the generated proxy classes which derive from it are thread safe.

Comment: @ChrisW: I actually just tried to remove my downvote, but I cant until you edit.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Thanks; but I've no edit to make, to this answer: I actually want to (learn how to) use ClientBase (safely). I only stumbled on this (old) question via Google https://www.google.com/search?q=asp.net+soap+thread-safe

Comment: Some people can't upgrade to the latest and greatest and are stuck with "legacy technology".  Keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Per this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.soaphttpclientprotocol.aspx

at the bottom under 'thread safety' it says this type is thread safe.  I do however not know that using it as a Singleton will be Thread safe.

Answer (score 1):

MSDN [makes no mention](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.soaphttpclientprotocol.aspx) that it's thread safe:

> **Thread Safety**
>
> This type is thread safe.

The class is safe, no mention of the object.

But it is safe to say that that it's **not** thread safe - no object in the .NET library is thread safe.

(At least i've never seen one)

Comment: Usually for non-threadsafe types the wording would be "All class members are guaranteed to be thread-safe. All instance members are not guaranteed to be thread-safe." so I'd assume that "This type is thread-safe" implies both class and instance members.

Comment: ok I'm confused... maybe a better question would have been: "Is creating an instance of the web service proxy for each call to a web method a performance downer?" :P

Comment: i assume by "type" they mean just the type (it's type information), as opposed to static class members, or instance members, which are not thread-safe.

Comment: I've written [another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21031308/49942) which says the opposite of yours. Which you think is right?