# Client WS-Proxy (SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke) thread safe?

Tags: asp.net, web-services

For a WebService i have a WS-Proxy.

The client using this WS-Proxy has 2 thread's:

TH1 is calling WS-Proxy Function 1
TH2 is calling WS-Proxy Function 2

Is this safe or should i use 2 WS-Proxy-Instances for each thread ?

Comment: I guess this is [similar question][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922214/is-soaphttpclientprotocol-thread-safe