# How to know if HttpWebClientProtocol class is Thread Safe?

Tags: c#

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922214/is-soaphttpclientprotocol-thread-safe) question, but the answers and discussions are confusing myself.

So I decided to check, but how could I do it? How to create a test to prove if `HttpWebClientProtocol` `class` is `Thread Safe`or not?

I have already done the following test:

1. Create one `HttpWebClientProtocol` to call a WS.
2. I create the WS by myself and have just a `Thread.Sleep(30000)` inside.
3. So I create two independent `threads` to call this `HttpWebClientProtocol` at the same time.
4. The result is: Both `threads` called the WS with no problems. (One `thread` didn't need to wait the first call ends)

with this test have I proved that the object **IS** `Thread Safe` and the "correct' answer of the other question is wrong??

Comment: And what is problematic to understand here? "No. It is not thread safe. the client must be in the Open state to enable calls. A simple scenario where one thread does client.Close() while another tries to call a method will fail."

Simplyfing, no, its not. If you want to test it, you should read about multithreading and how to use it. But you should also know that such test are not very reliable

Comment: Did you read *Thread Safety* in the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.httpwebclientprotocol%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: Second what @mikus said. Even if something is not thread safe, you could run dozens of tests and you're not guaranteed it will have any problems. Multithreading is a tricky thing and you're likely to get inconsistent behaviors across tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well... I have a better test for you.

[HttpWebClientProtocol Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.httpwebclientprotocol(v=vs.110).aspx)

Directly from MSDN. Here's a copy/pasta of what they have to say about thread safety:

> ### Thread Safety
>
> The properties on this class are copied into a new instance of a WebRequest object for each XML Web service method call. While you can call XML Web service methods on the same WebClientProtocol instance from different threads at the same time, there is no synchronization done to ensure that a consistent snapshot of the properties gets transferred to the WebRequest object. Therefore, if you need to modify the properties and make concurrent method calls from different threads you should use a different instance of the XML Web service proxy or provide your own synchronization.

### About thread safety

It's not about just "being available". But it's about making sure that data/state being affected by one thread does not affect the correct execution of the other thread.

If they share data structure and those structure are shared between threads, they are not thread-safe. The issue might not be easily apparent but on a system with large amount of usage of that class in a multi-threaded system, you could find some bugs/exceptions/weird behaviors that you will not be able to reproduce in a development environment and "only happens in production".

That my friend, is NOT thread safe.

#### About HttpWebClientProtocol and why it's not thread-safe

While the documentation is clear about being able to reuse the HttpWebClientProtocol, it is important to know that all the properties of the object itself are not going to be persisted to other requests created on another thread.

Meaning that if you have 2 threads playing with the `Credentials` property, you might end-up with some requests with different credentials. This would be bad in a web application with impersonation where requests could be done with a different credential and you could end-up with the data of someone else.

However, if you only need to set the initial properties once, then yes. You can reuse the instance.

Comment: Thank you by the answer, Oh so this topic of MSDN is exactly what I conclude by myself, really is `Thread Safe` but just if I don't need change the properties of the object for each call;

Comment: It is as "thread safe" as it is being mentioned on MSDN. No more. No less. No debate. No argument. That's it.

Comment: it Is but it isn't. hahaha

Comment: It isn't. You can make multi-threaded calls to it but if you start changing the properties (like `EnableDecompression`, etc...) then they might affect the other threads since you are basically acting on the same instance. That is the exact definition of "not thread safe". One change in one thread affects another thread. If you don't have to play with the properties more than once, then yes, you can reuse the objects in a multi-threaded scenario. But it is not thread-safe.

Comment: Good answer, now I understood. Answer Accepted :)